# SFML OpenGL Drawing Text

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I'm using SFML 2.0 as my windowing library with OpenGL. If I draw text using the `RenderWindow.Draw` method it doesn't display my OpenGL graphics, but when I take the Draw call out it does display the Graphics. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because `RenderWindow.Draw` changes some OpenGL state that you're not changing back after the call. Remember: OpenGL has a *lot* of global state. If you're lucky, SFML will have some documentation about what OpenGL state it sets so that you can reset it.

In general, either you should *always* use SFML drawing functions to draw your stuff, or you should *never* use them. You shouldn't go back and forth.